# Which protocols employ cover traffic

Tags: encryption, network

Do the protocols employed by wpa 2 and vpns use "cover traffic". A constant busy signal that would not allow for meta data analysis. If not is there a service that does this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they do not.

The only systems I know of that do traffic padding to defeat analysis are some [mix networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mix_network) such as [Mixminion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixminion).  It's a frequently-proposed thing for anonymizing networks such as TOR, but in practice, it's difficult to set up and tends to waste a great deal of bandwidth, increase latency, and constrain the total bandwidth of the network.